# Python: read a variable from list of a file in order to calculate equation

Tags: python, list, loops, variables, equation

I have to calculate different equation (we assume 3 reactions). Each one uses a different variable and I have to read this variable from a file `list.txt`.
So my idea is:

```py
f = open('list.txt')
lines = f.readlines()

k1 = lines[0]

r1 = k1 * 2  # this is first equation 
print(r1) 

k2 = lines[1]  # second equation
r2 = k2 * 2
print(r2) 

k3 = lines[2]
r3 = k3 * 3
print (r3)
```

My list is:

```
1
2
3
```

but this code prints first line two times, the second line three times and so on. Instead, I want that `k1`, `k2` and `k3` as a variable in order to obtain in this case:

```py
r1 = 2
r2 = 6
r3 = 9.
```

How can I do to obtain this result?

Comment: the values you read from the file will always be strings. You need the `int` function to convert them to numbers.

Answer (score 0):

it's clear [here](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/inputoutput.html) that if you read a file with readlines(), it will return a string. So, when you want to do a math calculation, you need to convert it to integer first

```
f=open('list.txt')
lines=f.readlines()

k1=int(lines[0]) # convert to integer

r1=k1*2  #this is first equation 
print (r1) 

k2=int(lines[1])  #second equation
r2=k2*2
print (r2) 

k3=int(lines[2])
r3=k3*3
print (r3)
```

Answer (score 0):

when you use the * operator on strings, you multiple them.
for example:  `"a"*3` will be `"aaa"`
and when you use it on numbers you perform the math operation.
for example: `3*6=18`

each line is string, so you need to cast the line to int:  `int(line)`.

also, you should consider use the [map](https://www.journaldev.com/22960/python-map-function) function.

it will make your life easier.

map perform given function on every item in the list.

for example:

```
result = list(map(lambda x: int(x) * 3, lines))
```

it takes every item in the list, cast it to int, and multiply it by 3.